# how to fix counting function

Tags: python, python-3.x

i am not to sure why the fish_pick is not working at the game, also I am not to sure why other errorS are occurring...……………………………………..I have already tried figuring it out however could not

```
import random
def fish_pick():
 fishlist = []
 # 10 fish
 Fish_species_1 = 9
 # 30 fish
 Fish_species_2 = 30
 # 15 fish
 Fish_species_3 = 50
 # 25 fish
 Fish_species_4 = 60
 # 20 fish
 Fish_species_5 = 90
 number = int(input("Amount of times the pick is done: "))
 for i in range(number):
     pick = random.randint(1, 100)
    if pick < 10:
        print('FISH_SPECIES_1')
        fishlist.append('FISH_SPECIES_1')
    if 10 < pick < 40:
        print('FISH_SPECIES_2')
        fishlist.append('FISH_SPECIES_2')
    if 40 < pick < 55:
        print('FISH_SPECIES_3')
        fishlist.append('FISH_SPECIES_3')
    if 55 < pick < 80:
        print('FISH_SPECIES_4')
        fishlist.append('FISH_SPECIES_4')
    if 80 < pick < 100:
        print('FISH_SPECIES_2')
        fishlist.append('FISH_SPECIES_5')
    print(fishlist)
    count_fish_species_1 = int(list.count("fish_species_1"))
    print(count_fish_species_1)
fish_pick()
```

Comment: Can you please give us further information like:
- what are you trying to achieve?
- what you have already tried?
- what kind of error are you facing?

I saw that your code isn't working because "list" isn't a declared variable. Did you mean to use "fishlist" instead?

Comment: Provide the traceback please.

Comment: I am trying to create a simulator which picks a random fish species from a 'pond' (and repeats this a lot of times)

Comment: `list` is a keyword used to declare a  python list. You cannot use it as a variable name.

Answer (score 0):

```
count_fish_species_1 = int(list.count(fishlist,"FISH_SPECIES_1"))
```